# How to write a function in R to automate selecting important features?

Tags: r

How to write a function to automate these processes:

1. Selecting important feature against 0.05 threshold
2. Selecting three most important features

So far mine is this, but its not working. I can list the features but can't write a function to do both!

```r
lm.fit <- glm(formula = Salary ~., data=train, family = binomial)
glm.coef.sig <- data.frame(summary(glm.fit)$coef[summary(glm.fit)$coef[,4] < .05, 4])
glm.coef.sig
```

Comment: AFAIK, such function already exists in R - it is called 'stepwise regression'. Did you try `step()`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example workflow:

```r
features <- "."
repeat{
  lm(formula=paste0("wt ~ ", paste0(features, collapse="+")), mtcars) -> lm.fit
  # get the coefficients that are significant
  summary(lm.fit)$coef[-1, 4] <.05 -> summ
  # check if the selected features are the features we already had if so break
  # if not change feature to selected features
  if(identical(features, names(summ)[summ])){
    break
  } else features = names(summ)[summ]
}
```

Comment: thanks. I tried it but i think i am bit inexperienced to do this considering my limited interaction with R. is ti possible for to write that function in details by looking at my posetd question!